# How to check convergence of the following series

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to check convergence of:

$1.\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+\frac{5}{4}}}$.I tried using Cauchy's root test but got limit=1.How to do it?

$2.\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1/2}}tan \frac{1}{n}$. i could not do this.Any help

Comment: Are you sure the denominator in (1) is $n^{n+\frac{5}{4}}$ and not $n^{\frac{5n}{4}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\tan(\tfrac{1}{n})<\frac{2}{n}$ if $n\geq2$, it follows:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\tan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)<\tan(1)+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\frac{2}{n}<\infty$$

Do you understand why this last sum converges?

Comment: Can u please tell me how did u come up with the inequality in the first line?

Comment: Because $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan(x)}{x}=1$, it follows there exists an interval $(-\delta,\delta)$ where $(1-\varepsilon)x<\tan(x)<(1+\varepsilon)x$ (definition of limit). Inserting $\varepsilon=1$ gives the inequality. You can also draw the graphs $\tan(x)$ and $2x$ and see that the inequality works for sufficiently small $x$ (of large $n$).

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}e\implies\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+5/4}}=\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\frac1{n^{5/4}}\le\frac4{n^{5/4}}$$

and now apply the comparison test and the $\;p$-series test